# how to implement AngularUI's Google Map

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angular-ui

I was trying to use AngularUI's Google-map module but it was not working. Instead of creating a new module i was trying to use it with my main module.

I used ng-app="DSApp"

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.min.map"></script>
<script src="components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

//AngularUI files start here

<script src="components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/event.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-ui-map/src/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I used **onGoogleReady** function at the top of my **app.js** file and inject dependancies in DSApp module like below.

```
function onGoogleReady() {  
  //cause error -> Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("map"), ['DSApp']);
}

var DSApp = angular.module('DSApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'DSFilters',
  'DSServices',
  'DSDirectives',
  'DSController',
  'ui.event',
  'ui.map'
])
```

At last i used html like below in my **index.html** page.

```
<div id="map" ng-controller="MapCtrl" >
  <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="mapOptions" class="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

And my controller is like this

```
.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function MapCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670), //causer error -> TypeError: undefined is not a function
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
}])
```

Sorry for the long post. I am a noob so i thought i made some silly mistake therefore i need to provide my code. What did i do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give more code? Perhaps a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co)?

Comment: Looks like you have ng-app and you're also manually bootstrapping is what the error is telling you.  Not sure about that particular google map implementation but in the one I'm using there's no need to manually bootstrap angular, believe you may be using the updated version though.

Answer (score 3):

***This answer is a guess without a Plunk or JSFiddle***

**Causes of your errors:**

- **Already bootstrapped:** I'm assuming you have `<html ng-app="DSApp">` in your HTML file. When AngularJS loads, this `ng-app` attribute tells it to automatically bootstrap your entire document. This leads to your 'already bootstrapped' error.
- **Undefined is not a function:** When Angular bootstraps the document, it tries to set up your controller. This occurs, most likely, before Google Maps has loaded. Thus, `google.maps` is not yet defined when your controller executes.

*Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368285/delay-angular-app-initialization)*

**Possible solution:**

Attach your controller to a different module, one that isn't bootstrapped via `ng-app`.

I pulled this from the source code for [Angular UI's UI.Map demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/):

```
function onGoogleReady() {
    console.log("Google maps api initialized.");
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("map"), ['DSApp.map']);
}

angular.module('DSApp.map', ['ui.map']).controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, you clarified how the bootstrapper works for me. Nice one Tyler :-)