# How to wait for a promise in a Run block in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I really need some data to be loaded before bootstrapping angular. For this reason I've created a `run` block/ Within this `run` block I call a method on a service which load some data from the server. Since this is a async call, JavaScript gets further with execution, which results in some undefined objects in my app.

I am working with routes, but it is not an option to work with the `resolve` property.

Could someone provide a solution on how to wait for a promise to be ready in the `run` block?

EDIT:

Thanks to the given answers, I have solved it by manually bootstrapping angular:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax('/Data/GetDropdownData', {type:'POST'}).done(function (response) {
        app.run(['ListService',  function (ListService) {
            ListService.setData(response);
        }])

        angular.bootstrap(document, ["sma"]);
    })
})
```

Comment: promise.then(function(data){
 $rootScope.data = data;                           
}); but I think it's too easy ^^ and you are not sure to have it ready in your controller

Comment: @Whisher Thanks for the reply, but this is indeed not an option. I really need the data to be loaded before starting up the app.

Comment: So maybe manual bootstraping would be an option http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap   <script>
       angular.element(document).ready(function() {
         angular.bootstrap(document);
       });
    </script>

Comment: yep, as @FedorSkrynnikov said, manual bootstrap is the way I would go

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov: Thanks for the comment, but where do I place the code for loading my data?

Comment: I added answer and put comment regarding place there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented would put it here

You may try [manual bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

```
<script> 
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document); 
   });
</script>
```

Of cause in this case you cannot use controllers and angular way of getting data. I think you would have to load your data by jQuery, bootstrap your angular in jquery callback and then init your scope variable with data you got from jquery.

Comment: Marked as answer because Fedor was the first.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data) SO question - it shows how to initialize an AngularJS service with asynchronous data.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FYznxP3xe8dxzwxs37hi?p=preview) is a plunkr example from that question showing the use of AngularJS services like $http to load the configuration and then do further initialization.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539428/215922) answer has a great explanation and shows an example of waiting for the DOM to load like this (plunkr example from that answer is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AC0iJBQEJcRTd1LLfsn3?p=preview)) :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the only solution is [manually bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) your application. Maybe you can find some help in this question [Delay Angular App Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368285/delay-angular-app-initialization) and in this small article [Manually bootstrapping AngularJS for asynchronous loading in Internet Explorer](http://icelab.com.au/articles/manually-bootstrapping-angularjs-for-asynchronous-loading-in-internet-explorer/).

As stated in the previous article, to do a manual bootstrap:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
});
```

Be sure to remove all the refences of `ng-app` in your `HTML` to stop the auto bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

an other solution since I would not ommit parts of my application but I still have to wait for things to be loaded.

the bootstrap directive (not affiliated to twitter bootstrap) :

```
myApp.directive('myBootstrap', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      promise: '=myBootstrap'
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="ctrl.isReady" ng-transclude></div>',
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.isReady = false;

      //else an array of promises can be filled by a service
      $scope.promise.then(function() {
          ctrl.isReady = true;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and the related plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/vx4aWS?p=preview