# How to make controller wait untill app.run finishes

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

In my application, I'm getting some data in app.run using $http.get()
The result from this is required to proceed to the controller.
Currently my controller is executing before the completion of this $http.get
How can I make my controller's execute after the execution of $http.get()

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies) {
var currentLanguageId = angular.fromJson($cookies.get('mykey')).UserInfo.Country;

    $http.get('myurl').then(function (serviceInfo) {


        $rootScope.serviceURL = serviceInfo.data.serviceURL;

    }, function (error) {
        alert('error service info');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`run` can't handle asynchronous work at the moment. See this issue : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4003

You have multiple solutions for that. You can get your data without Angular and start Angular manually ( [How to wait for a promise in a Run block in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697598/how-to-wait-for-a-promise-in-a-run-block-in-angular) )

Or you can use the resolve of your route to do this : [AngularJS : Initialize service with asynchronous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/angularjs-initialize-service-with-asynchronous-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular scope event`. When data is fetched, you can broadcast an event from `$rootScope` to all controllers and receive this event in target controller.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$rootScope.$broadcast();`in the app.run and then use `$rootScope.$on()` in your controller.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies) {
    var currentLanguageId = angular.fromJson($cookies.get('mykey')).UserInfo.Country;
    $http.get('myurl').then(function (serviceInfo) {
        $rootScope.serviceURL = serviceInfo.data.serviceURL;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('serviceInfoReceived')
    }, function (error) {
        alert('error service info');
    });
});
```

In your Controller

```
app.controller ('myCtrl' , function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("serviceInfoReceived", function(){
         console.log($rootScope.serviceURL)
    });
})
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, however the $rootScope.$on solution will not always work. It will depend on the timing of the controller registering the listener. The way I have found that works is to set a $rootScope property, and then configure a recursive timeout to wait for it to be set.

```
function waitForRun() {
  if($rootScope.runFinalized){
    // do something
  } else {
    $timeout(waitForRun, 500)
  }
}
waitForRun();
```

and after the last .run block:

```
.run(function($rootScope) { $rootScope.runFinalized = true; })
```

Ugly, but it works.